# Layering gradients on element

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

So I have this little progress bar from jQ UI. http://jsfiddle.net/BnqaJ/
But to the current gradient, I want to add stripes like this. http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated But not animated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) to create a CSS pattern that overlays your progress bar. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/Qw6uv/2/. Changing the angle of the gradient appears to stop the gradient moving with the element: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/Qw6uv/4/

It degrades gracefully, without support it will just not appear, leaving the progress bar intact.

Please do see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) for further info, and browser support information